# How to return multiple values from this program to API host server

Tags: python, json, rest, web-scraping

This is a program that scraps data from an internship site and then converts it as a rest API which posts data as JSON to the local server

NOTE: - This is a part of the whole program which is functional on its own.

```
import scrapped_intershala
from flask import Flask,  jsonify 


import json
import requests
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
start_link='https://internshala.com'

html_text = requests.get('https://internshala.com/internships/game%20development-internship').text                  #for game development
soup= BeautifulSoup (html_text,'lxml')

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def run():
    company_name= soup.find_all('div', class_="heading_4_5 profile")
    stipend = soup.find_all(('span'), class_="stipend")
    location = soup.find_all(('a'), class_="location_link")
    start_date = soup.find_all(('div'), class_="item_body", id="start-date-first")
    link_to = soup.find_all(('div'),class_="heading_4_5 profile")


    for name, sal, loc, Sdate, LK in zip(company_name, stipend, location, start_date, link_to):                            #zip takes iterable or containers and returns a single iterator object, having mapped values from all the containers. 

        #name below are only here as these need formatting
        nm = name.text.replace('\n','')                                         #name of company
        dt = Sdate.text.replace('\n','').replace('Immediately','').strip()      #date of joining as intern
        #name above are only here as these need formatting

        answer={
            'Company name' : nm,
            'Stipend' :  sal.text,
            'Location': loc.text,
            'Date of joining as intern' : dt,
            'For more information link for internship': start_link+LK.a['href']
            }

        queries_json = json.dumps(answer)
        return queries_json

    

        #print(f'''Company name: {nm}\n\nStipend: {sal.text}\n\nLocation: {loc.text}\n\nDate of joining as intern: {dt}\n\nFor more information link for internship: {start_link+LK.a['href']}\n\n\n\n\n\n''')








if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=7000)              #this command may chance for every machine /  / here host 0.0.0.0 is used as this machine uses a private  IP
```

This program only returns one value to the local server rather than returning all values to the server

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement in python breaks the execution so if you use it in a for loop it break the loop.

What you should do is use the foor loop to create a list object and then return it instead:

```
all_answers = []
for item in ...:
    answer = {...}
    all_answers.append(answer)
return json.dumps(all_answers)
```